# Animation <Set> property android:repeatMode will not accept an int

Tags: android, xml, animation

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3arepeatMode) I would put either a 1 or 2 as the value, however, upon attempting to launch my application, I get the error:

```
Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'repeatMode' with value '1').
```

and my Animation XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:repeatMode="1" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" >
    </alpha>
    <alpha
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the enum value of "restart" or "reverse" there if you're settings this values from XML.

Besides, animations don't run one after the other as you seem to think given your animation XML. If you want the other animation to start afther the first one, set the "startOffset" attribute as well (like android:startOffset="1000").

Answer (score 0):

You use instead of android:repeatMode="1" to  android:repeatMode="reverse".